# Automatically Read CSV file into Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, csv

I have some JS code which is used to render locations on Google Maps using the APIs. I need to JS code to periodically read a csv file, which is updated using a Python script polling some other REST APIs. 
So basically, Python code Calls a REST APIs and updates a csv with location.
I can't seem to find how to read this csv file from the local system using JS code.

Comment: Are we talking about client-side JS or server-side JS here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serve your local CSV file on a web server such as [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in order for a browser executed javascript to be able to read the data.

I would really recommend nginx as it is lightweight and deals with static content (what you have) very well.